# THREEJS - Preserving the exact same PNG result as Sprite

Tags: javascript, three.js, sprite

Is there a way to add an Image as Sprite that is not affected by any filter, scale or zoom? I just want to add a PNG to the 3D world and this PNG must preserve the exact same size even when moving the camera.

I’m trying this with sizeAttenuation=false but the result of the PNG is blurry, plus I have to change the scale because by default is huge on the scene.

Is there other technique to achieve this?

Comment: Do you need your sprite to be an exact pixel size, like 64 x 64px? What behavior should it have when the browser is resized, for example, resizing the window to 1/2 its height?

Comment: The browser size does not affect my canvas/scene. So in that case I expect to have the same 64x64px render.

Comment: @EnZo You can use an orthographic HUD overlay. See https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_sprites.html.

Comment: @EnZo You might also consider using [THREE.CSS2DRenderer](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/renderers/CSS2DRenderer), which is basically an HTML/CSS overlay on top of your WebGL `<canvas>` element. You can see [an example of it here](https://threejs.org/examples/#css2d_label), it is not affected by zooms or rotations, only positions. That way your image would retain the exact pixel size you need.

Comment: @WestLangley Will the orthographic camera render the image pixel-perfect?

Comment: @Marquizzo I see this a bit dirty.